# Using same password hash for account activation

Tags: hash, authentication, activation-codes

I've used password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_BCRYPT) to create a hash and store in the user table. It will be used for login verification.

Since hashing is a one way function,
My question is can I use the same hash as the account verification code in the activation email send to user.
Will it compromise security since knowing the hash doesn't reveal the password.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would compromise security because an attacker with access to the email account (either presently or at any future point in time if the email is never deleted), could run a password guessing attack on the hash.

If would be better to generate a 128-bit key using a [CSPRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator), this can be emailed to the user as is. On the server-side you would want to hash this using SHA-2 for storage, because that way if your activation table data was ever exposed, an attacker could not activate accounts that do not have valid email addresses. Note that no salt is needed for automatically generated keys of this strength.

This approach is fairly simple, and mitigates the risk in sending the password hash directly.